# How to allow booting from usb on MacOS Catalina

Tags: windows, macos, boot, macos-catalina

I bought an external SSD and put win10 on it using WinToUsb. Now I have an ssd with Windows but if I connect it to my mac I can't set it to boot from that drive.

I searched for the answer and I found out that I have to go inside the recovery mode of my mac and that at the startup security I'll find a check for "allow boot from usb disk". Now the problem is that I can't find that window where I can set this option, instead I only get a small window which allows me to set a password for boot-firmware but I don't need that.

Is there any workaround or how to enable booting from USB? I'm on a Macbook which is running the latest Catalina firmware. I can't boot from system-preferences and the disk isn't showing when I'm holding down the option key.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have booted into recovery mode and gotten to the MacOS utilities screen, you need to look past the window in front of you.

Rather, go to the menu at the top of the screen, find "Utilities" and click on it. Select "Startup Security Utility" from that menu.

You will likely need to select "No Security" and "Allow booting from external media."

That should allow what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yesterday i figured it out that i have a little older macbook which dont has this T2 chip which means i dont need to allow anything in the recovery settings. My ssd wasnt showing in the bootlist because some error... i tried to install windows with Rufus and now it goes without a problem. So i guess i was simply unlucky with the installation with WinToUsb or something went wrong. But now everything works x)